# How do I increase the axis size on an ROC Curve in R?

Tags: r, font-size, curve, roc

How do I increase the axis size in the ROC curve? I have tried this code but I can only increase the label and "AUC:0.9201" sizes. I want to increase the size of the x and y coordinates as well.

[image: 1]

I have tried this code.

```
# Use the prediction function to generate prediction result:

pred.rocr <- prediction(p2, test$Ped.RLV)



# Using the performance function to obtain the performance measurement:

perf.rocr <- performance(pred.rocr, measure = "auc", x.measure = "cutoff")
perf.rocr@y.values[[1]] <- round(perf.rocr@y.values[[1]], digits =4)
perf.tpr.fpr.rocr <- performance(pred.rocr, "tpr", "fpr")

# Visualize ROC curve using plot function

plot(perf.tpr.fpr.rocr, colorize = T, main = paste("AUC:", (perf.rocr@y.values)),lwd=4,cex.lab = 3,
     cex.axis = 3,
     cex.main = 3,
     cex.sub = 3)
abline(a=0, b=1)
```

I have tried cex.axis = 3, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please include all loaded libraries in your code.

Comment: Try `par(cex.axis=2)` before your `plot` command to increase the axis *tick labels*. And if you want the axis *lines* thicker, add `box(lwd=2)` at the end.

Comment: What is meant by the “size of the axis”?

Answer (score 1):

The help page for `plot.performance` mentions that the axis is an exception for modifying the graphical parameter. It then suggests that you can increase/decrease the size of the axis tick labels with

```
par(cex.axis=2)
```

If you also want to increase the thickness of the axes (the box that is shown around the plot, then use

```
box(lwd=2)
```

You can change 2 to a larger number if desired. Your commands would then be:

```
library(ROCR)
...

opar <- par(cex.axis=2)

plot(perf.tpr.fpr.rocr, colorize = T, main = paste("AUC:", (perf.rocr@y.values)),
     lwd=4,
     cex.lab=3,
     cex.main = 3,
     cex.sub = 3)
abline(a=0, b=1)
box(lwd=2)
par(opar)
```